# Modular templates in django

Tags: python, html, django, templates

I am getting started with Django, and I'm trying to make a modular template, but I don't know how. Now, I have the following files:

1- base.html (which provides basic layout for all the website):

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My site</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/bootsrap.min.css' %}" />
</head>

<body>
<h1>Test title</h1>
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

2- index.html (main db read)

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% if latest_smartphones_list %}
<ul>
{% for s in latest_smartphones_list %}
    <li><a href="#">{{ s.brand }} {{ s.name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
<p>No smarphones available.</p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Finally, i wanted to add a third file, called menu.html which would contain the site menu. I wanted to add it in the base.html file. I've been thinking about doing it in the following way, but i doesn't work:

```
{% load 'menu.html' %}
```

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: The three-level template is an example in the [template inheritance reference documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/templates/#template-inheritance)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `{% load 'menu.html' %}` you have to use `{% include 'menu.html' %}`

Docs:

- [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include)
- [load](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#load)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is using the [include templatetag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include)

```
{% include 'menu.html' %}
```

which includes a template and renders it with the current context.

NB: whenever you are in trouble, [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/) is the best place to go to! Always keep this in mind